# How to disable a JavaScript hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, html

I just get a script from a website to put it on my own site, but it has a hyperlink on it and I want to disable that, here is the script:

```
<script language="javascript" src="http://www.parstools.net/calendar/?type=2"></script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the "hyperlink" you're referring to the script's `src`? That's how the script is loaded. What are you attempting to do by "disabling" it?

Comment: For those who don't want to open the src, it's one line: document.write("<a href='http://www.ParsTools.com/'>1389/1/31</a>");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672331/how-to-change-font-color-inside-an-existing-script), you may want to try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Simple Demo</title> 
  </head> 

  <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function () {
       document.getElementById('calendar').innerHTML = 
          document.getElementById('calendar_hidden').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML;
     };
  </script>

  <body> 

    <div id="calendar_hidden" style="display: none;">
       <script src="http://www.parstools.net/calendar/?type=2"></script>
    </div>    

    <div id="calendar" style="color: red;">       
    </div>

  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the link is always going to be the same, and you know how to get that string into a variable, this should work:

```
str = str.replace( "<a href='http://www.ParsTools.com/'>", '' ).replace( '</a>', '' )
```

Edit in response to comment

This isn't best practice, but.. Wrap the js include in a div:

```
<span id="whatever">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
</span>
```

Then

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  str = document.getElementById( 'whatever' ).innerHTML
  str = str .... // what i said before
</script>
```

This solution doesn't require jQuery, which it looks like you don't want to use.

Comment: yes the link is always going to be the same, but where I should add this: str = str.replace( "<a href='http://www.ParsTools.com/'>", '' ).replace( '</a>', '' )

Comment: I've done this as far as I get you, see if I go wrong anywhere
<div id="calendar">
<span id="whatever">
       <script language="javascript" src="http://www.parstools.net/calendar/?type=2">
    </script>
     
<script type="text/javascript">
  str = document.getElementById( 'whatever' ).innerHTML()
  str = str.replace( "<a href='http://www.ParsTools.com/'>", '' ).replace( '</a>', '' )
</script>
    </div>

thanks.

Comment: You don't need to put my script in the <div>, but it works as long as we're ignoring standards :) Don't forget to close the `span` as well! (between the </script></div>, you need </span>)

Comment: @user320946: I think you need to use the `window.onload` event, as in the example of my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672421/how-to-disable-a-javascipt-hyperlink/2672508#2672508. Otherwise, the string replacement will happen before the external script is loaded.

Comment: thanks every one, Daniel way works just fine, and one more thing, I cant vote up yet, as far as I dont have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean the script creates a new hyperlink element on the page. You could simply write your own JavaScript (after the external script), which disables it. With jQuery that would be something like

```
$('#hyperLinkId').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Evgeny, the script actually is a Calendar, and when I add this part to my page, it appears fine, but when you mouse over on it, it has a link to it's website (parsitools.net) and I want to disable that, and about jQuery, I really don't know anything about that and how I can add this to my page, I would really appreciate if you explain it much clearly for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you place that script inside of a `<div id="something">` you can do the following:

```
var something = $('#something a');
something.replaceWith(something.contents());
```

assuming you include the jQuery library.

See "[How to remove only the parent element and not its child elements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170004/how-to-remove-only-the-parent-element-and-not-its-child-elements-in-javascript)"

Comment: I put a div behind my script like this: <div id="calendar"><script></script></div> and where I have to put your codes then ? sorry for being so unfamiliar with jQuery

Comment: and also how can I add jQuery library to my page ?

Comment: You can download it from their website (http://jquery.com) or link a `<script>` tag to the Google-hosted version (http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/index.html#jquery). Since the code is so simple inside of the remote script you might be better off with a pure JS solution similar to hookedonwinter.

Comment: Check out jquery.com. Tons of very awesome documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the "script file" in question and i'm very confused.

This is the entire contents of the link: http://www.parstools.net/calendar/?type=2

```
document.write("<a href='http://www.ParsTools.com/'>1389/1/31</a>");
```

It doesn't appear to be a calendar at all.

Can you provide more information regarding your using of this script file?

Comment: it's a calendar for some middle-east region actually